# Why is that an object defined using a type alias extends { [key: string]: unknown } and an object defined using an interface doesn't?

Tags: typescript, interface, typescript-generics, type-alias

I have the following function that should take an array of objects of many types and return a sorted result of that array. Since it may receive many object types, I'd like it to be generic.

[Typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

Hence, the following: `<T extends GENERIC_OBJECT>` and `arr: T[]`

```
interface GENERIC_OBJECT {
  [key: string]: unknown
}

export function sortArray<T extends GENERIC_OBJECT>
(arr: T[]) : T[] {
    return arr.sort();
}
```

It should be working fine. But there is one weird behavior.

See this:

[image]

Look at the results:

[image]

The `interface` object type does not work. And the `type alias` object type works.

See the error:

[image]

Error message in text format:

> Argument of type 'OBJECT_V1[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'GENERIC_OBJECT[]'.
> Type 'OBJECT_V1' is not assignable to type 'GENERIC_OBJECT'.
> Index signature is missing in type 'OBJECT_V1'.(2345)

**QUESTION**

Why do I get different results whether my object type is defined by using an `interface` vs a `type alias`? How can I make it work with an interface in this case?

Comment: Why constrain T at all?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I can try to avoid it, but I first constrained it because in my real use case I add a `tempProp?: string` to the `GENERIC_OBJECT` that I use to temporarily add the normalized `string` of the field I'm going to sort for. It actually let's you select a string property to sort for on the second parameter. I removed everything to make it simpler for the question.

Comment: Please include code and error messages as text, rather than as pictures of text.